# Find Replace a Function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML page where there are many `<a onclick="javascript>`

What i need to do using Jquery is find the below tag as it is

`<a onclick="javascript:OpenNewWindow('/help_options.php?ID=2', 350, 250);" href="javascript:void(0);">`

and replace it with

`<a onclick="javascript:OpenNewWindow('/help_options.php?ID=2', 600, 500);" href="javascript:void(0);">`

Note

1) the values 350 is changes to 600 and 250 is changed to 500
2) there are also many similar tags but i want the code to do Exact find and replace of the above tag.

IS this possible ?

Comment: Why do you need this? The `javascript:` label is superfluous in the `onclick` handler. You should remove it.

Comment: instead of constants, why not you use variable(s) to control height and width?

Comment: Could you send the entire page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be looking to change the inline `onclick` Javascript even if I could.

A better approach is to late-bind everything in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MyAnchorID1").click(function(){
        OpenNewWindow('/help_options.php?ID=2', 350, 250);
    });
});
```

So, when you did want to change the event, you `unbind` then re-`bind`. I.e. do something like:

```
$("#MyAnchorID1").unbind("click").click(function(){
        OpenNewWindow('/help_options.php?ID=2', 600, 250);
});
```

Of course, that approach just does it for an anchor with a particular id. You could just select 'a' to get all anchors.

A simpler solution might be to define an object literal:

```
var myDims = {width:350, height:250};
```

Use that in the function:

```
 OpenNewWindow('/help_options.php?ID=2', mydims.width, myDims.height);
```

And just change the values of this when you need:

```
myDims.width = 600;
```

Comment: I tried the following at http://tinyurl.com/3m5dt9t but its not working, nothing is happening on click

Comment: Works fine for me. I get a window 1000 in height

Comment: its not working on chrome, Ff which browser are you checking ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('a').unbind();
 $('a').click(function(){
   OpenNewWindow('/help_options.php?ID=2', 600, 500);
 });
 });
```

Comment: I tried the following at http://tinyurl.com/3m5dt9t but its not working, nothing is happening on click

Comment: you need to run the jquery - put it within a $(document).ready(function () { section as shown above.

Comment: That worked but i dont see height nor width is changed ?  tinyurl.com/3m5dt9t